# Microsoft visual c++ 14 or greater is required error

Tags: python, visual-c++

I am trying to install [this package](https://github.com/rsprouse/ultratils.git) in Python, but I get this error:

> Microsoft Visual c++ 14 or greater is required

I installed Microsoft Visual 2022 but I still get this message. Any suggestions of what's going on?

Comment: You should probably list the steps you've tried so far for installing it.

Comment: Have you installed the latest C++ compiler with the Visual Studio?

Comment: @AKA I installed the package, set the path in python and then hit 'python setup.py install'.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Microsoft Visual 2022", but what you need are the Build Tools.